# Como fazer soma em um select case Oracle

Tags: oracle, select, case, soma

Eu estou tentando fazer uma soma em um select case, mas aparentemente não é válido, aparece o seguinte erro "   ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected". quando eu retiro o "+1" do código dá certo, mas eu preciso dele kkk

```
select case 
    when to_number(to_char(data,'D')) < to_number(to_char(to_date('01-jan-'||to_char(data,'RRRR')),'D')) then to_number(to_char(data,'WW'))+1
        else to_number(to_char(data,'WW'))
 end AS Semana_Certa
```

from producao

Comment: Olá Matheus! Tentei reproduzir seu erro mas não consegui, peguei sua consulta e substitui o "data" por "sysdate" e inclui a cláusula "from" (acho que você esqueceu dela) e rodou sem problemas, nos dê mais detalhes para podermos ajudá-lo.